# Python: assert does not print out error message

Tags: python, assert

I am using the assertion in a multithreaded environment to help me catch early bugs. But it turns out that when assertion failed, python3.7 just terminates silently without printing the error message that I want to see. Thanks for helping in advance.

Here is the sample code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import random
from time import sleep
def task():
    assert False, "no assertion output, why?"
    print("Executing our Task")
    sleep(5)
    result = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(10):
        result = result + i
    print("I: {}".format(result))
    print("Task Executed {}".format(threading.current_thread()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    task1 = executor.submit(task,1)
    task2 = executor.submit(task,1)
    #task(), directly calling and the assertion failure message will be printed out.
```

I ran it using the command `python3.7 test.py`

I think I used python assertion in a wrong way because I assume it to be the assert function in c++. If I change the assertion to throwing an exception, the above code does not print too. Am I supposed to catch the exception?

BTW, directly calling it, and the assertion failure message will be shown though.

Comment: Does the assertion message print if you just call the `task` function directly?

Comment: assert will check if the value is true, for your function to execute you need to set your assert to True instead of False.

Comment: @HenryWoody yes, directly calling it and I get the error message. If I put it in the threadpool, I need to try and except to catch it in order to print, otherwise it crashes silently and I can't use to to detect bugs.

Comment: @SimbarasheTimothyMotsi Thanks. For this example, I am just triggering the assertion failure in order to see the whether the error message be printed out or not.

Comment: @HanXIAO did you try putting the output message in brackets? `assert False, ("no assertion output, why?")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are retrieving the futures (assigning the return values to `task1` and `task2`), but doing nothing with them. Try something like this.

```
for future in futures.as_completed([task1, task2]):
    if future.exception() is not None
        # Process the results here.
```

This will remove the race you currently have.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what is means for "retrieving from futures, but doing nothing with them"? I feel like if this is in c++ code, when the thread execute that code, the assertion failure will happen and error message will be printed out though.

Comment: @HanXIAO In C++, you would have a race too if you would get an `std::future` object, and not call its `get` method. It is exactly the same case here.

Comment: Thanks. So does it means that regardless of theadpoolexecutor or processpoolexecutor, if exception is thrown on the "top" level in child thread/process and there are no try-except clause in child thread/process to catch it, there is no default handler for the exception? And that's why we need to have the parent to handle their children's exception? My erroneous assumption is that there must be some default "system" exception handler for the child thread/process, so even if the exception is not processed in parent process, it will be handled by the default "system" handler with error printed.

Comment: @HanXIAO It's not even that. In your code above, you cannot even assume that the exception was thrown by the child - you have a race between the script terminating, and the child failing the assert.